# 2 column design, how to put my left column scroll at right of my page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, multiple-columns

I have a design with two columns with their scrolls. I have a problem with it. How can I put the scroll of my left column totally at right of my page?

here is a screenshot of what i'm looking for: http://500milligrammes.com/fmzz/final/news/zzz/onetwo.jpg

Here is my link: http://500milligrammes.com/fmzz/final/news/zzz/index.html#

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>

<link property="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/font/font.css"/>
<link property="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/style.css"/>
<style type="text/css">
*, *:before, *:after { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }
</style>
</head>

<body id="top">
<div style="height: 100%;" id="container">
  <div style="height: 100%; width:100%; position:absolute;" id="o-wrapper" class="o-wrapper">
    <div class="columnsContainer">
      <div class="leftColumn">
        <div style=" margin:0px auto; border:0px solid #fff; width:auto;">
          <div class="lazy">
            <img class="imgstylefirst" data-src="img/2.jpg" src="../../css/news/loading.gif" alt=""/><br/>
            <div class="creditstyleempty">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="lazy">
            <img class="imgstyle" data-src="img/3.jpg" src="../../css/news/loading.gif" alt=""/><br/>
            <div class="creditstyleempty">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="lazy">
            <img class="imgstyle" data-src="img/4.jpg" src="../../css/news/loading.gif" alt=""/>
            <div class="creditstylelast">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="rightColumn">
        <div style="padding:70px 0px 50px 0px; margin: 0px 20px;">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      <div style="margin: 0px 20px 20px 20px;">
        <span style="100%" class="newstitle">TITLE</span>
        <p style="margin-top:-7px;" >Blablabla</p>
        <hr class="gridnews">
        <div class="flipper">1</div>
        <div style="margin:10px 0px 0px 0px; display:block;" class="flip">
          <span style="width:100%; height:auto;">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?" But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"  ...
          <br/><br/>
          <a href="#">Read more >></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      <div style="margin-top:20px; " class="flipper">2</div>
      <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="flip">blabla</div>
      <div style="margin-top:20px; " class="flipper">3</div>
      <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="flip">blabla</div>
      <div style="margin-top:20px; clear: left;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="../../css/infinitescroll/jquery.unveil.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".lazy img").unveil(1000);
});
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../css/news/readmore.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes it works fine, but how can I have my left column's scroll totally at right of my page, i don't want to have it just at right of my pictures, I want it at right of my right column too

Comment: Give your rightColumn a `margin-top` in stead of a `padding-top`. It will put the scrollbar in the correct position.

Comment: that's done thank you ;), have you an idea of how can i put my left scroll totally at right of my page ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. Can you provide a screenshot with the expected result?

Comment: instead of moving it to right side, add it on left side of page.

Comment: screenshot is available here : http://500milligrammes.com/fmzz/final/news/zzz/onetwo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well you want to have two scrolls next to each other like on FB.

You can do that:

Set right column styles:

```
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
width: 50%; // it is just example, use what you want here
right: 0;
```

The right column can be direct child of body or container.

[Than you can use this plugin for jQuery](https://larsjung.de/jquery-scrollpanel/)

If you use plugin I propose you just need to add following script:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $(".rightColumn").scrollpanel();
});
</script>
```

Ofcourse you can place it beside other scripts you have or (this is the best way) in external file.

Don't forget to include jQuery and plugin in your scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/your/dowloaded/plugin"></script>
```

To fix left column scrollbar position you should not have any margin - it should be full width. Instead set child div correct width and you done.

Comment: this is what you mean - >screenshot is available here : 500milligrammes.com/fmzz/final/news/zzz/onetwo.jpg

Comment: So you want just one scroll for this page?

Comment: yes, but i want scroll works for column only when mouse is inside them, so if we're in left column, only left content scroll and when we're in right column only right content scroll. I did some modifications, it works for you or i'm wrong ?

Comment: Ok, just to mention - I think this is not really good idea in UX context - users can be a little confused how to use that scroll corectly and also you will have problem how to left focus on left column while someone go to right edge of the screen to use scrollbar. Anyway I can help you, but we will need custom scrollbar and jQuery, did you ever work with it?

Comment: yes i can, but Facebook did it and it works perfectly, you can see it in action when you scroll on your wall and when you go at right, to see who is online or offline. there two scroll in the same place for two different column

Comment: I think we still are a little missunderstood :) On Facebook you have scroll for all page scrolling, and also second (hidden) scroll for chat list - it is not the same scroll, is that what you want?

Comment: yes lol, two different scroll in the same place for two different column ;) My all page will be my left column and my chat list will be my right column

Comment: Ok, now we clear (we should disscuss on chat but I have to low reputation). Give me while, i'll write you how to do that.

Comment: did you find a solution @jazzgot